# Accessing physical storage of Expo SQLite database

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

I am developing an android application using React-Native under the expo CLI.
I am trying to create and write to a database using the 'expo-sqlite' library.
My testing environment is my android phone using the Expo application by scanning the QR barcode displayed in the metro bundle on my browser.

My code is presented below:

```
OnClick = () => {
 let db = SQLite.openDatabase('testdb', 'version1')
 let str = 'CREATE TABLE contacts (    contact_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,    
            last_name TEXT NOT NULL,    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,    phone TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);'
  db.transaction((txn) => {
  txn.executeSql(str, [],
  (txn, rs) => console.log('successfull'),
  (error) => console.log(error)) }) }
```

The above query executes successfully, therefore; I presume that a database was physically created.
I would like to access the physical database file that was created on my device.

Some posts say that the database file is located under `data/exp.exponent/files` however, this directory is empty. 
I tried logging the `console.log(FileSystem.documentDirectory)`, it points to `file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FMyProject-195b03bc-663c-49e9-aac3-2d9bdf0a3d37/`; however I could not find that path on my phone.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to transfer the DB file to my PC using the expo sharing library. First do some imports:

```
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
```

The following code will open a sharing window on which you can share your db via whatsapp or outlook. This way you can download the file via whatsapp web and see what is going on in your database.

```
await Sharing.shareAsync(
   FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite/main', 
   {dialogTitle: 'share or copy your DB via'}
).catch(error =>{
   console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! : D. Wondering how am i supposed to manage this in-phone DB

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I found the following:

```
1- Import FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'; default saving location is : 
   FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite/databasename' 
2- There is no convenient way to access the database file in the path stated in point 
   1(unless your Android device is rooted); however, a turnaround consists of using the MediaLibrary module, and saving 
   the database file to DCIM folder (Android).
```

Comment: August 2020 update: I was able to go to the location revealed by that Filesystem snippet and was able to copy thee contents of my database to my desktop and all the data was inside. So fortunately #2 seems no longer valid.

Comment: @TK123 - how were you able to "go to the location"? Through Android Studio? It's unclear

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally managed to figure it out:

FYI I am working with the iOS Simulator.

I was struggling to find the folder where expo creates the database.

1. I installed the File System Package `npx expo install expo-file-system`
2. Then I wanted to see what `FileSystem.documentDirectory` will log out, because I didn't know where expo keeps my stuff.

So I simply created a button and onClick I logged the value it returns

```
FileSystemPath = async () => {
    console.log(FileSystem.documentDirectory)   
}
```

3. In my terminal navigated to the path. It should look something like

`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AF763EBC-48F3-4238-A1E5-0DB2B43359D0/data/Containers/Data/Application/115EEA6B-5A65-47DE-96F9-1A4126EB2F2D/Documents/ExponentExperienceData`

4. After I was in the `/ExponentExperienceData` I opened it in Finder
   with `open .`
5. Then I was able to see 2 directories. One of which was holding an SQLite folder and inside was my database. Then simply opened the file with any app that reads a .db file (in my case TablePlus).

FYI My database was created simply with

```
const db = SQLite.openDatabase('myDabaseName.db')
```

nothing more.

Hope this helps someone.
Cheers