# expo-sqlite how can I download database file?

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo, expo-sqlite

I'm using expo-sqlite in my React Native app, I would download database file for executing queries in my editor.

How can I download SQLite database file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing physical storage of Expo SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769593/accessing-physical-storage-of-expo-sqlite-database)